# Lightning tree indentation

Tags: lightning-aura-components

[image]

I am trying to indent both the parent and child record in the lightning tree but child indent is not working properly:

```
account1
    >contact1
          >Contact 2
   account 2
        >contact 3
             >contact 4
```

---

```
<aura:component controller="TreeController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="data" type="List" default="[]"/>
    <lightning:tree header="Accounts" class="slds-is-selected" items="{!v.data}" onselect="{!c.handleSelect}"/>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
console.log("Going here");
var action = component.get("c.getAccountList");  
 action.setParams({ accountId : component.get("v.recordId")});
 //action.setCallback(this, result => helper.parse(component, result));
 action.setCallback(this, function(response) {  
   var state = response.getState();
   console.log('state'+state);
   console.log('response'+JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
   if (state === "SUCCESS") {  
     var result = response.getReturnValue();
     helper.parse(component, result);  
     console.log('result----'+JSON.stringify(result));
   }  
 });  
 $A.enqueueAction(action);
 },
    handleSelect: function (component, event, helper) {
    //return name of selected tree item
    var myName = event.getParam('name');
    alert("You selected: " + myName);
    }
})
```

---

```
({
  parse: function(component, result) {
    var accounts = result;
    console.log('accounts'+JSON.stringify(accounts));
    var parents = { undefined: { items: [] }};
    var parentcontact = { undefined: { items: [] }};
    console.log('parentsA'+JSON.stringify(parents));
    accounts.forEach(account => parents[account.Id] = { items: [], name: account.Id, label:account.Name, expanded: false});
    console.log('parentsB'+JSON.stringify(parents));
    accounts.forEach(account => { if(account.Contacts) { account.Contacts.forEach(contact => parents[account.Id].items.push(parentcontact[contact.Id] = { items: [], name: contact.Id, label:contact.Name, expanded: false}))}});
    console.log('parentsC'+JSON.stringify(parents));
    accounts.forEach(account => { if(account.Contacts) { account.Contacts.forEach(contact => parents[account.Id].items.push( parentcontact[contact.parentId__c].items.push(parentcontact[contact.Id])))}});
    //account.Contacts.forEach(contact =>parentcontact[contact.parentId__c].items.push(parentcontact[contact.Id] ));
    console.log('parentsD'+JSON.stringify(parents));
    accounts.forEach(account => parents[account.ImmediateParent__c].items.push(parents[account.Id]));
    console.log('parentscontact'+JSON.stringify(parentcontact));
    console.log('parentsE'+JSON.stringify(parents[undefined].items));
    component.set("v.data",parents[undefined].items);
  }
})
```

---

```
   @AuraEnabled  
public static List<Account> getAccountList(Id accountId) {  
 List<Account> finalvalue = new List<Account>();  
 for(Account accA : [ Select Id, Name,(SELECT Id,Contact.Name,parentId__c, Phone FROM contacts),ParentId,ImmediateChildFlag__c,ImmediateParent__c,ImmediateParent__r.Name From Account Where ParentId =: accountId or Name LIKE'TreeAccount%']) {   
      finalvalue.add(accA);  
     }            
 System.debug('finalvalue:::' + finalvalue);  
 return finalvalue;    
}
```

Comment: When talking about correct ident you mean correct parent child structure in account contacts hierarchy? Sorry but your code your code is kinda chaotic for me and I have problems with getting what you want to achieve

Comment: yes if you see my screen shot ident is happening but it happens for multiple times.I have self lookup in contact.i am using foreach to iterate and ident it in right contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would part this task into couple of pieces:

TreeWrapper:

```
public class TreeWrapper(){
    @AuraEnabled
    String name;
    @AuraEnabled
    String parent;
    @AuraEnabled
    Boolean expanded;
    @AuraEnabled
    String label;
public TreeWrapper(String name, String parent, Boolean expanded, String label){
   this.name = name;
   this.parent = parent;
   this.expanded = expanded;
   this.label = label;
}
```

Second part:
Query Accounts and Contacts. Iterate over them and create TreeWrapper instances where name = id of an Account/Contact, parent = ParentAccountId if its account or Account Id if it's Contact. Label = Account/Contact name that you want display in tree and expanded = true if you want this node expanded by default.

Third part: Fetch data into frontend

```
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
            //get account and respective contact list, and initialize with items
            var data = response.getReturnValue();
            var tree = this.getNestedChildren(data, null);
            component.set('v.items', tree);

        } else {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Method that creates tree in javascript:

```
    getNestedChildren :  function (models, parentId) {
    const nestedTreeStructure = [];
    const length = models.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        const model = models[i];

        if (model.parent == parentId) {

            const items = this.getNestedChildren(models, model.name);

            if (items.length > 0) {
                model.items = items;
            }

            nestedTreeStructure.push(model);
        }
    }

    return nestedTreeStructure;
}
```

References
Tree algorithm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444296/how-to-efficiently-build-a-tree-from-a-flat-structure
My answer for similar case (but with tree grid):
[Hierarchy diagram in Lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191768/hierarchy-diagram-in-lightning/215512#215512)

Comment: 1974566 in the second part you are specified that parent for account and contact both account id but my requirement account will indent based on parent account id and contact will indent based on parent contact id if you see my screen shot account will form tree and contact will be placed under each account and third account will be indent based on the parent account and then contact will indent based on parent contact which is self lookup to contact.

Comment: So assign parents as you wish when creating instances of your wrapper class. Algorithm will still work